# Set-ADuser 'serialNumber' attributes from CSV

Tags: powershell

I have tried to set the attribute 'serialNumber' using a CSV file but I keep getting an error message after hitting Enter.

Here's my script

```
ipmo activedirectory
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\test.csv
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $sam = $user.sAMAccountName
    $serial = $user.serialNumber
    Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $sam} -Properties serialNumber | 
    Set-ADUser -Replace @{serialNumber = $serial}
}
```

The format of my CSV

```
sAMAccountname;serialNumber
name;2357
```

The command stops at '-Replace (...)'

Do you have any idea where I am wrong?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Try @{serialNumber = "$serial"}. If that doesn't work, it would be helpful if you could edit the error in to the question.

Comment: add your error message

Answer (score 3):

Pass `-Delimiter ';'` argument to `Import-Csv` cmdlet:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\test.csv -Delimiter ';'
```